# Understanding nesting vs parent in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class called: QuestionList, which creates Questions children, along with (nested) Alternatives:

`QuestionList` render:

```
<Question wording="wording...">
  <Alternative letter="a" text="bla ..." />
  <Alternative letter="b" text="ble ..." />
  <Alternative letter="c" text="bli ..." />
  <Alternative letter="d" text="blo ..." />
</Question>
```

1. Who is "alternatives" parent? Question (because it is nested) or QuestionList (because it created)?
2. How can pass a Question event handler to Alternative?

If I use

```
<Alternative onClick={this.handleClick} (...) />
```

It will pass QuestionList's handler (and not Question's handler - the desired behavior).

**QuestionList**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import Loader from 'react-loaders';
import Question from './Question';
import Alternative from './Alternative';

export default class QuestionList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        questions: []
    };
}

loadItems(page) {
    let questions = this.state.questions;

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start='+ page * 5 +'&_limit=5')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            response.data.map(p => {
                questions.push(p);
            });

            this.setState({questions});
        });
}

handleClick() {
    alert("QuestionList");
}

render() {
    let items = [];
    const loader = <Loader type="ball-scale-multiple" />;

    this.state.questions.map((p, i) => {
        items.push(
            <Question
                title={p.title}
                key={i}
                id={p.id}
            >
                <Alternative onClick={this.props.handleClick} key={1} text={ p.title } letter="a" />
                <Alternative onClick={this.props.handleClick} key={2} text={ p.title } letter="b" />
                <Alternative onClick={this.props.handleClick} key={3} text={ p.title } letter="c" />
                <Alternative onClick={this.props.handleClick} key={4} text={ p.title } letter="d" />
                <Alternative onClick={this.props.handleClick} key={5} text={ p.title } letter="e" />
            </Question>
        )
    });

    return (
        <InfiniteScroll
            key={1}
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={this.loadItems.bind(this)}
            hasMore={true}
            loader={loader}
        >

            <div className="justify-content-center" id="react-app-questions-list">
                {items}
            </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
    );
}
}
```

**Question**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Question extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        answer_class: "unanswered"
    };
}

handleClick(isCorrect, e) {
    // alert(this.props.id + ": " + isCorrect);
    alert("Question");
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={"list-group list-group-bordered mb-3 " + this.state.answer_class}>
            <div className="list-group-item">
                <div className="list-group-item-body">
                    <h4 className="list-group-item-title">
                        { this.props.title }
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            { this.props.children }
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

**Alternative**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Alternative extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <a className="list-group-item list-group-item-action react-app-alternative">
            <div className="list-group-item-figure">
                <div className="tile tile-circle bg-primary">{ this.props.letter }</div>
            </div>
            <div className="list-group-item-body"> { this.props.text }</div>
        </a>
    );
}
}

export default Alternative;
```

Comment: Can you post the full working React classes for the 3 components? It's hard to answer your question without seeing the relationship in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Who is `Alternatives` parent? `Question` (because it is nested) or `QuestionList` (because it created)?

`Alternative` parent is `Question`. If you check `Question.props.children` array (remember that `Question` is just an object), you will see `Alternative` types there.

```js
function Question({ children }) {
  console.log(children); // children[0].type === Alternative
  return children;
}
```

Read more about React elements as objects [here](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/#react-elements).

---

> How can pass a Question event handler to Alternative?

You can **inject** props to `Question` children, for example:

```
function Question({ children }) {
  console.log(children);
  const injectChildren = React.Children.map(children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { letter: `${child.props.letter}-injected` })
  );
  return injectChildren;
}
```

For this you need to read about [React Top-Level API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#overview) and refer to [React.Children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) and [cloneElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

Check out the example:

[image: Edit gracious-stallman-0jho6]

Answer (score 0):

Handlers are intended to work on context ... where state is managed .. then in `<QuestionList/>`. Prepare specific, parametrized handlers and use them to update common state.

Chaining 'desired' (more granular or more specific) handlers to pass values through the structure can't be practical. It won't be efficient, either.

Take a look at data/state flow in 'Formik` project - form, validations, fields. It can be a good source of inspiration for this problem.

---

**`<Question/>` and `<Alternative/>` should be stateless, functional components** - you don't need them to be statefull. KISS, YAGNI...

Comment: I guess Question should be stateful because I'd like to change question's style if it was correctly answered.

Comment: No, you can pass `isCorrect` prop - look at formik ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm still learning React and thought class x functional components was more like a syntatic sugar.